# Subgroups of order $pq$ in nonabelian groups of order $p^{2}q$, where $p>q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a nonabelian group of order $p^{2}q$ where $p>q$. As $G$ is nonabelian we have $q\mid p-1$ or $q\mid p+1$. I want to show the two following facts, but I couldn't complete my proofs.

> 1) If $q\mid p+1$ then $G$ has no subgroup of order $pq$.

In this case $q\mid p+1$ is equvalent to $q\nmid p-1$ and so by the classification of groups of order $pq$ if $G$ has a subgroup of order $pq$ it should be cyclic. 
Therefore here we should show that $G$ has no element of order $pq$.

I suppose that $x$ be an element of $G$ with order $pq$ but I couldn't find a contradiction.

> 2) If $q\mid p-1$ then $G$ has a nonabelian subgroup of order $pq$.

In this case as $q\mid p-1$ and $G$ is nonabelian, the number of sylow $q$-subgroups of  $G$ is equal to $p$. So by assumption that $Q$ is a sylow $q$-subgroup of $G$, we have $|G:N_{G}(Q)|=p$ and therefore $N_{G}(Q)$ is a subgroup of order $pq$.

I don't know how to show $N_{G}(Q)$ is nonabelian or maybe there is another nonabelian subgroup of order $pq$.

Comment: See [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwibnZqE_fHnAhXCAewKHZQFBOIQFjAAegQIBRAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.purdue.edu%2F~lipman%2F5532011%2Forder-p%255E2q.pdf&usg=AOvVaw24OjOS_D3vymlgVoMeze7L). There  $p$ and $q$ are interchanged in the notation.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you. Sorry, but I can't find the answer to my question in this paper.

Comment: The text gives a *classification* of all groups of order $p^2q$ with primes $p>q$. So you can just check for each group whether or not 1) or 2) is true.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I see what you mean, I've checked with GAP as many groups as I can and I've seen the facts that I've written is true for them. I want to proof them directly.

Comment: It is directly proved during the classification. You just have to follow to two cases of $q\mid p^2-1$ there.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I want to prove them by group theory, this text uses matrices.

Comment: Matrices are also group theory, think of the group $GL_n(K)$ consisting of invertible matrices. Or semidirect products of groups, like the affine group, which is a group of matrices. And exactly this, the semidirect product, you need in group theory and for this question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Thank you for your help and attention.